# ffmpeg choose outbound IP (eth0 or eth1)

Tags: ffmpeg, ip-address

I have 2 IP addresses on my server.

```
 $curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.co      
111.111.111.111

 $curl --interface eth0:0 ifconfig.co      
222.222.222.222
```

So via curl I can switch via interfaces so my IP address changes when I visit any url based on eth IP

How can I use same thing via ffmpeg?

For example,  if  want to  access this video via ffmpeg  (it uses 111.111.111.111 to access it)

```
 ffmpeg -i 123.com/video.mp4
```

how can I access same video from my second IP 222.222.222.222 ?

Is there any command like this, perhaps?

```
ffmpeg --interface eth0:0  -i 123.com/video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg itself cannot do that. What you want is a mechanism that chooses the appropriate Ethernet interface depending on the remote IP (or even domain). This is something that you have to configure in your operating system.

A related question to this topic: [Linux: routing based on domain names](https://superuser.com/questions/1185861/linux-routing-based-on-domain-names/1210156) — you'll find several solutions including using `route` for IP-based routing and VPNs for domains.